# Mozilla 3.0.8 and Chrome height in em bug workaround

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, textarea, mozilla

I've got a *textarea* inside a *div*:

```
<div id="textareawrapper">
  <textarea id="chat"></textarea>
</div>
```

...and *CSS*:

```
#textareawrapper {
    border 1px dashed pink;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    position: absolute;bottom: 0em;left:7.5em;right:7.5em;height: 7em;
}
#textareawrapper textarea {margin:0;padding:0;width: 100%;height:7em;}
```

IE 7 renders it fine: the height of the *textarea* is equal to the height of the wrapping *div*. In Mozilla and Chrome the the wrapping div is rendered 7em high, but the textarea is some 20-25px not hight enough, so that there is a gap between the bottom of the textarea and the bottom border of the div. Does any one know how to fix this?

Comment: Firefox updated to 3.0.9 http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/3.0.9/releasenotes/

Comment: Or try updating to the beta version 3.1b3, maybe they fixed it for you http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-beta.html

Comment: And while I'm at it, there is a Chrome beta http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textarea is using a different font by default, so the size is different (as ems relate to the text size).

Add this:

```
#textareawrapper textarea { font-size: 100%; font-family: inherit; }
```

Tested & working in FF3