# Aligning textarea in a form

Tags: css

Ive used the following css code to align my form elements:

```
form {  position:relative; }
form input { position:absolute; left:11em; }
```

However, the textarea element is not aligned correctly with the rest of the elements. I tried the following, but that didnt work

```
 form input,textarea { position:absolute; left:11em; }
```

Any way to fix this ?

Thank You.

Comment: Whenever posting up a CSS problem, it always helps to know what browser you're seeing the problem in, and/or if it's cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

No-one is going to be able to solve this without seeing the current result; I generally avoid absolute positioning as a rule unless doing something particularly complicated like tooltips, can you not achieve what you want using margins?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a Firefox, em-specific bug.
I think it's related to this bug about Firefox textareas and its font: [Mozilla 3.0.8 and Chrome height in em bug workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789479/mozilla-3-0-8-and-chrome-height-in-em-bug-workaround)

Your positioning should work if you add the following code:

```
form { font: 11px Arial; }
form textarea { font-size: 100%; font-family: inherit; }
```

Also, another workaround is using *pixels* instead of em's.

Answer (score 0):

This does not address your question, but why not use "text-align"? Absolute positioning to place form elements sounds a bit odd in my ears.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use absolute positioning in this way, have you considered using `margin` instead of `left`? As the others have pointed out, it's difficult to troubleshoot your problem without more information.