# How to get rid of gap between textarea's bottom and its wrapping div in chrome browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, textarea

I am trying to create a box like description field in https://gist.github.com/ page. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DCzBM/) is my minimal example. As you can see (in only chrome) there is a gap at the bottom of textarea between the wrapping div. How can I get rid of it?

```
<div style="
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;">

      <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
         <textarea style="width: 194px; resize: vertical; border: 0px; height: 124px; margin: 0px;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

There is a similar but an old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789479/mozilla-3-0-8-and-chrome-height-in-em-bug-workaround) and the answer is not helpful.

Comment: Try to apply a css reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Remember to insert the reset css file before your actual css code.

Comment: Have you seen the jsFiddle link? I think there is no need for a css-reset in jsFiddle, am I wrong? Moreover this little piece of code behaves the same in minimal HTML file without any other style.

Comment: Since jsFiddle does not work on the network environment i'm in now (blame the network admins :P) I was using my expertise to give an insight. That is why I haven't done it as an answer, since I was not able to test it.

Comment: well, shame on admin guys over there :) By the way CSS reset doesn't provide a `display:block` style for `textarea`s which indeed solves the problem. See my answer and thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extra space under textarea, differs along browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144843/extra-space-under-textarea-differs-along-browsers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the trick was giving the textarea `display: block;` credits to [yuxel](https://twitter.com/yuxel)

just a note: css reset(yahoo's one) doesn't change textarea's display.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="
padding: 3px;
background-color: #eee;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 200px;">

  <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin:0; padding:0;">
     <textarea style="width: 194px; resize: vertical; border: 0px; height: 124px; margin: 0px; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is that it?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot, in the div delete margin:0;

Comment: your solution would work, but it'll be better for the sake of the project if he firsthand resets his css

Comment: Yeah true, but he didn't said that he got any css style.

Comment: well this doesn't seem to change anything, please check this code out in jsFiddle and in a *chrome* browser.